# Error retrieving Sku details

Tags: android, ios, google-api, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have developed an app using [Ionic Native In-App Purchases](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase/) and submitted it to the Google Play Store as an Alpha release.

I could view the available purchase options:

```
this.iap.getProducts(this.PRODUCT_IDS).then((products: any[]) => {
    ...
});
```

I then set up a test user to test in-app purchases. I tried to make a purchase:

```
this.iap.buy(item.productId).then((data) => {
  return this.iap.consume(data.productType, data.receipt, data.signature);
}).then(() => {
    ...
}).catch((err) => {
  this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {
    this.doAlert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
  });
});
```

And ever since, when I try to make other purchases to test the app, I get the following when trying to get the available purchases:

> Error retrieving Sku details

I have read that this error may be caused by a pending order that needs to be canceled, but I cannot find where to do so (I have looked at "`Order Management`", but there are no orders).

This is working perfectly on `iOS`, so I know my code is correct, and also on `Android` I could view the available purchases before I did the test purchase.

I have also [read](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase/issues/55) that I should wait 14 days for Google to remove test orders, but it's been 16 days today, and I still get the error.

I have also since released my app as Beta in the Play Store, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I have the same issue here!

Comment: I spoke to Google support, they couldn't help. Very unhelpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found the problem, I just add the play store key in the manifest.json file inside src/ folder of the Ionic 2 project.

```
{ "play_store_key": "<Base64-encoded public key from the Google Play Store>" }
```

I hope this will help your problem too.

Comment: Thanks, I just looked at my `manifest.json` file, and I see the `"play_store_key"` is absent. I did originally have it, maybe it got deleted. I will try it. Thank you. Glad you got your problem sorted.

Comment: Thank you, I have battled with this for ages, and that was my issue, so it works now too.  Not sure how my key got lost.